# Rewrite URL for a specific taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I registered a post type of 'product', and also registered a taxonomy 'poruct-cats' for this post type.

When I want to access to product-cats it seems like below:

```
example.com/poruct-cats/a-product-name
```

The above url is not seo friendly.

I Like the url be like below:

```
example.com/product/poruct-cats/a-product-name
```

I spent lots of time for reading about WordPress rewrite in codex but I finally could not do that.

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following [`rewrite` argument](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Arguments) in your `register_taxonomy()` call:

```
register_taxonomy( 'product_cat', 'product', array(
    'rewrite' => array(
        'with_front' => false,
        'slug' => 'product/poruct-cats',
    ),

    // Other arguments
));
```